# Using mvc model to display markers on Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to send a IEnumerable model that includes the latitude and longitude values that I want to display on Google map that I display on my web site.

Here is the code that I am using in my view to display the map:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.modelname>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Map View";
}

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=My-API-Key" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style>
    #map_canvas img {
    max-width: none;
    }
</style>


<style>
    .infoDiv {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>

<h2>Map</h2> <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Tags/Create">Create Tag &raquo;</a>
<hr />

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>


@section scripts {
<section class="scripts">

    <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    Initialize();
});


function Initialize() {


    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var Liverpool = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.71452, 27.097047);


    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: Liverpool,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-26.674359 , 27.095391);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Tate Gallery'
    });


    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')


    var data = [
              { "Id": 1, "PlaceName": "Liverpool Museum", "OpeningHours":"9-5, M-F","GeoLong": "53.410146", "GeoLat": "-2.979919" },
              { "Id": 2, "PlaceName": "Merseyside Maritime Museum ", "OpeningHours": "9-1,2-5, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.401217", "GeoLat": "-2.993052" },
              { "Id": 3, "PlaceName": "Walker Art Gallery", "OpeningHours": "9-7, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.409839", "GeoLat": "-2.979447" },
              { "Id": 4, "PlaceName": "National Conservation Centre", "OpeningHours": "10-6, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.407511", "GeoLat": "-2.984683" }
           ];


    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
            'map': map,
            'title': item.PlaceName
        });


        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<div class='infoDiv'><h2>" + item.PlaceName + "</h2>" + "<div><h4>Opening hours: " + item.OpeningHours + "</h4></div></div>"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

    })
}


    </script>
</section>
}
```

I am currently pre-populating it with dummy data, but I am unable to retrieve the data from my model.

How will I be able to use the model, as I am unable to run a foreach loop in the script?

Thanks in advance!

Found the Answer! I needed to return my JSon data from my controller using this method:

```
public ActionResult MapView()
{
    var tags = db.Tags.ToList();

    var jsonTags = from x in tags
                   select new Tags
                   {
                       GeoName = x.GeoName,
                       GeoLat = x.GeoLat,
                       GeoLong = x.GeoLong
                   };

    return View(jsonTags);
}
```

thanks for all the help! The Json.Encode was also needed!

Comment: you want to do multi maps with multi data model?

Comment: No, I want to display multiple markers on one single map? :) Markers that I store in my model

Comment: Is it fine like that then? :)

Comment: Yes and alwayes do that :)

Comment: @Jets take a look at https://github.com/jmelosegui/GooglemapMvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your view Json.Encode can convert your list to JSON array

RAZOR

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourModel))
```

ASPX

```
<%=html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourModel)%>
```

-

```
var data = <%=html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourModel)%>;
```

Comment: if you are using razor view try `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourModel);`

Comment: Ah yea i see, I understand how to use the @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourModel)) now, but I am not sure about the formatting, because the map is not displaying the markers at all?